# iPhone app dimmed and unresponsive after upgrading to Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

After upgrading to Xcode 5, after compiling and executing an application, the screen appears dimmed and doesn't react to tap and pan gestures, both on a real device and simulator.  Other similar apps compile and execute fine on iPhone. Anyway, it is not completely blocked. It's still responsive to Game Center, iCloud and rotation events. Strangely, it works fine on iPad.

Deployment target is set to 6.1.

Any hint?

Comment: How is the app initialized? Can you post the code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I've found the bugs and all works fine now. I've added an explanation to my question.

Comment: Please write your solution as an answer below, then mark it as an answer so others know this question is resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must apologize!

I've found the answer. Trying to figure out what could I had done wrong I realized that I had been trying changes on background color and alpha values of the main view and I did forget to leave them as they were before at IB. So, on changing alpha value of the main view, all its subviews appeared dimmed.

Responsiveness was restored by checking again "User Interaction Enabled" box. Don't ask me how could I uncheck it inadvertently.